# Property 'find' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'. any

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I have simple angular 2 form  code is below

```
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="formcss">
    Username<br>
    <input type="text" formControlName="username"><br><br>
    <div>
    Email<br>
    <input id="email" type="text" formControlName="email">
    <div *ngIf="myForm.find('email').valid">Invalid Email</div><br><br>
    Password<br>
    </div>
    <input type="text" formControlName="password"><br><br>
    <h3>Hobbies</h3>
    <input type="text"><br><br>

    <button>Add Hobby</button>
    <button type="submit" [ngStyle]="{ background:'green'}" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

I am trying to show message "invalid email" is email filed does not pass validator, but getting this error

```
error_handler.js:45 EXCEPTION: self.context.myForm.find is not a function
```

I am using final release of angular 2. Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`find`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.5/modules/%40angular/forms/src/model.ts#L263) was removed from `AbstractControl` (super class of `FormGroup`) in RC6. You should use [`get`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html#!#get-anchor) instead

Answer (score 0):

I was doing an angular course and  it had this lines:

"!myForm.find('email').valid"  and "!myForm.find(['userData','email']).valid"

it seems that find is no longer in AbstractControl and was replaced by get.

**Replace find with get** leave the rest as it was before.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.